# Android Development Studio (bumblebee) Kotlin question Suggested Fix not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Android Development Studio (Bumblebee).  When I am developing a Java application, If I have a TextView with hard coded text I see the yellow triangle for Suggested Fix.
When developing Kotlin, with the same TextView hard coded text, I'm not seeing the yellow triangle for Suggested Fix.  Does anyone know how to fix this.  I'm new to Kotlin and would like to have all of the assistance I can get when learning it.
Also, I'm not having any issue when developing a Java App.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

just move the cursor to the position that is marked as warning or error and if you don't see the icon of help then press `ALT+ENTER` if you are using Windows or Linux or `OPTION+ENTER` if you are using Mac. this will open the dialog as you usually do with tapping the icon.